# htaccess : rewrite url from /id to query ?id=

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite in htaccess an address with a dynamic id.

- My old address: http://localhost/id (id number is dynamic int)
- My new adress: http://localhost/ad.php?id=id

What I've tried and doesn't work:

```
# Rewrite --- http://localhost/1 => http://localhost/ad.php?id=1

RewriteRule ^1$ /ad.php?id=1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) /ad.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The following explains the rules above:

**([0-9]+)**
allows any digit, and only any digit, 1 or more times.

**[QSA,L]**
appends this to your internal scripting query string, and makes it the Last rewrite rule executed.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But only after a modified the second path to absolute path http://www.example.com/ad.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]